# Powershell pass Hashtable with Empty Key Value to Call Operator

Tags: powershell, hashtable

```
#Should execute this: invoke-some -Name "name" -Firstname "Firstname" -Emptyargument
#NOT works: invoke-some -Name "name" -Firstname "Firstname" -Emptyargument $true
#works: invoke-some -Name "name" -Firstname "Firstname" -Emptyargument:$true

$cmd="invoke-something"
$arguments = @{Name="name";Firstname="firstname";emptyargument=$true;

$result=& $cmdlet @arguments 2>&1
```

So how can i pass `-Emptyargument` without some Value. From my knowledge a hashtable cannot have a empty value.
Anyone knows a workaround? I cannot change whole architecture for this edge-case.

Comment: This is how you're supposed to pass switch parameter when splatting. Your idea is correct but your execution is wrong. You do not have a bracket close to your `$arguments`. Remove the last semi-column, since it serves no purposes and add a bracket close so you have `$arguments = @{...}` Reference: [about splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: oh this is a typo. in my real code there is a closing bracket. but the "invoke-something" failed is there is a value for -emptyargument flag. if i define emptyargument="" in the hashtable it is failing too

Comment: @insane_IT can you provide more information? A case when this works, a case when it doesn't and also the error? Basically, when using splitting you pass parameters to the cmdlet. If that cmdlet has *mandatory* parameters then you must pass something, it has nothing to do with the *call operator*. As I said, provide the error if possible.

Comment: i found out that the hashlist is not the problem. i have a php script which passes parameter to the powershell skript. in this way the command is not executed successfully. if i call the ps script with the exact same parameter it works (print out the params in the ps script shows no difference for both way). so i think the topic of the threat is not suitebale for the problem.

Comment: i simple reboot without any futher changes solved the problem. computers are strange sometimes. anyway: thanks for help